# What does 'The Soviet armies to the east' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The Soviet armies to the east, including their dominance by force of
>   Eastern Europe, not only fostered cooperation through NATO but U.S.
>   aid also helped foster market reform in Western Europe. U.S. aid often
>   depended on market reform;

–[*Violence and Social Orders: A Conceptual Framework for Interpreting Recorded Human History*](https://books.google.com/books?id=e48I6-Xgt8UC&pg=PA131&dq=%22fostered%20cooperation%20through%20NATO%20but%20U.S.%20aid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI5bOT-YSTyQIVB6SICh04jgpk#v=onepage&q=%22fostered%20cooperation%20through%20NATO%20but%20U.S.%20aid%22&f=false), by Douglass C. North, John Joseph Wallis, and Barry R. Weingast

Comment: Located in those parts of the world that were east of NATO's position in Western Europe. There, "to" could be paraphrased "in" but "to" adds the nuance of pointing to the remote location relative to an express or implied reference location.

Comment: When I read this "including their dominance by force of Eastern Europe" seems entirely redundant.  What's an army for if not dominating by force?

Comment: The sentence at the beginning of the same paragraph is even worse: "Violent international competition also tempers policymaking in open access orders, especially during periods of intense competition." Surprisingly (to me) this comes from a [book published by Cambridge University Press](https://books.google.com/books?id=e48I6-Xgt8UC&pg=PA131&dq=%22fostered+cooperation+through+NATO+but+U.S.+aid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI5bOT-YSTyQIVB6SICh04jgpk#v=onepage&q=%22fostered%20cooperation%20through%20NATO%20but%20U.S.%20aid%22&f=false), albeit by three U.S. professors.

Comment: I didn't get your point about the other sentence. Could you explain more?

Comment: @CandiedOrange armies can dominate through mere presence.

Comment: It talks about the effects of "violent international competition ... especially during periods of intense competition"—as though violent international competition might occur under conditions other than intense competition. War seems pretty intense to me. I also have no idea what "open access orders" are, though (presumably) if I read the book, the authors would tell me. Even the book's subtitle seems overwritten: "A Conceptual Framework for Interpreting Recorded Human History." To me, "recorded human history" is like "recorded human records"—no recording, no history.

Comment: The issue is kind of like saying "right" or "left" in a theatre. Do you mean house right or stage right? I'm not surprised to learn this was a collaboration. The old saw "to really screw up, you need a committee" seems to prove itself once again.

Answer (score 2):

"Soviet armies to the east (of Western and Central Europe)" seems like a logical inference based on the rest of the sentence, but the whole sentence is awfully gawky in my opinion. Obviously, unless things went badly wrong, ALL Soviet armies should have been to the east of Western Europe anyway. To distinguish the Soviet armies of the Soviet east from the Soviet armies of the European east the authors should have said something like "the armies of western Russia" or "Soviet armies in western Russia".